# Retrieve both string and json of body using koa js

Tags: node.js, middleware, koa, body-parser

I use koa js with [bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser), suppose client send body like this:

```
{ "first": "1"           , "second": "2"}
```

what I want is the original body as string with no changes (JSON.stringify changes the order of fields and remove spaces then I can't use it). I try to use [raw-body](https://github.com/stream-utils/raw-body) that gives me the string of body, so I have to parse it to JSON.

is there any middleware that give me body as both json and original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both the raw string and the JSON, get the string, keep a copy, then parse it to JSON.

```
var getRawBody = require('raw-body')
app.use(function* (next) {
  var string = yield getRawBody(this.req, {
    length: this.length,
    limit: '1mb',
    encoding: this.charset
  })
  var json = JSON.parse(string)
  // do something with "string"
  // do something with "json"
})
```

Note: You have to run `getRawBody()` against `this.req`, since that's node's raw http `request` object. `this.request` is koa-specific and won't work.

Comment: yes I know this (wrote in the question), I'm looking for a way that don't parse the string to json or convert json to string. thanks for the reply.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't really a typical use case and doubles the memory footprint, plus it requires just one extra line of code. So a pre-packaged solution is unlikely to exist. Doing it manually (as shown above) is pretty much your only option. Even if there was a pre-packaged solution, it would do the same thing (parsing the string to JSON) behind the scenes.